# How to homogeneously mix a very small quantity of a salt in a very large quantity of another salt?

Tags: salt

I'm trying to recreate `super salt` which is a mixture of:

- 90 parts `NaCl`
- 10 parts `Monosodium Glutamate`
- 1 part of `disodium 5'-ribonucleotides` (1 part `disodium guanylate` and 1 part `disodium inosinate`)

Anyhow this means that only 1% of final product is made of `disodium 5'-ribonucleotides`, which is usually a rounding error in my recipes.
How could I make sure that I have an homogeneous mixture of the 3 ingredients?

Solutions I thought:

- Mix them in an empty bottle and shake for 30 minutes
- Die the `disodium 5'-ribonucleotides` and visually check that an homogeneous solution has been reached
- Create a oil / water based slush? (I think it's a bad idea)

Is there a better approach I could use to achieve my desired result, without buying any expensive machinery?

Comment: Don't mix all at once. Take your minor component, add 10 parts of the rest, mix, then add the remaining 90 parts.

Comment: As @IvanNeretin, use serial dilution, unless it's cereal dilution.